# Failed to enable constraints using c# tableadapter

Tags: c#, datatable, constraints, tableadapter

I have probably a really silly question but after lots of research on google and trying several things I didn't find any solution for my issue.

I am using a `TableAdapter` and run the following query:

```
 SELECT        
    table1.column2, table2.column2
 FROM          
    table2 
 INNER JOIN
    table1 ON table2.ID = table1.table2ID
 WHERE        
    (table1.column2 = @something)
```

Running the following code

```
   DataTable DT = new DataTable();
   DT = TableAdapter.GetByColumn2("something");
```

works fine unless the resulting `DataTable` is empty. When it returns a value I get the following error:

> ConstraintException was unhandled
>   Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values
>   violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.

If I run the query manually it returns exactly the information I need at this point and SQL doesn't complain about any constraints.

I am a real newbie to C# and would really appreciate if anybody could help.

Thanks...

Comment: If you try to run this query in SQL Server, definitely its going to return 1 column only, what exactly the error you get? If you need both column2, use alias

Comment: @Piyush: he said that the above Query runs fine in sql

Comment: @Khurram:- run it in sql , It going to return 1 column, but as question feels OP requires both column in result?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6d68/4 .. OP has to include what exactly error he gets..then exact solution only be provide

Comment: The query is supposed to deliver only one column - in fact exact the information I need at this point. Therefore I believe that the issue is somewhere linked to the DataTable.

Comment: I updated my post with the error-message I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you query return only 1 column, if you want both column in your result set use alias

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6d68/4

You have to use alias in your sql query so that query return both column.

```
SELECT table1.column2 as Table1Column2, table2.column2 as Table2Column2
    FROM  table2 INNER JOIN
        table1 ON table2.ID = table1.table2ID
    WHERE  (table1.column2= @something)
```

This may be not the exact problem OP faced, but OP has to include the Error he gets to get exact solution.

Comment: i dont think so...i thing the problem is not a query but the C# Code for filling Datatable from TableAdapter

Answer (score 0):

You Should Fill Your DataTable From DataAdapter like this

```
        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT        table1.column2, table2.column2
        FROM          table2 
        INNER JOIN
           table1 ON table2.ID = table1.table2ID
         WHERE        (table1.column2= @something)";
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        SDA.SelectCommand = cmd;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SDA.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably found the issue and would be happy if anyone could revise my thoughts if neccessary.

It seems that the TableAdapers in C# require the SQL statement to include all columns of the given table within the results. If I just omit one column the code will issue this constraint error.

Adding additional columns as aliases from other tables is possible, but they need to be added as additional columns to the result.

Personally I currently don't understand the deeper sense behind this behavior as I believe that SQL should be used in a way to retrieve exactly the data I need at a given point. TableAdapters somehow require me to issue a "select * from table" every time I use them.

Please guys - correct me if I understood anything wrong in this context.

Thanks!